# Pandas return rows with matching substring to string

Tags: python, string, pandas, filter, substring

I have a dataframe where i want to check for every row if one column of substring is contained in another column of string. If a character in Subposition column exists in the string of Position column, return True, other wise return False in the Check column. (L = left, R = Right , S = straight, U = u turn)

```
 Position   Subposition  Check
   L           R         False 
   L           L         True
   LR          L         True
   SRU         L         False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) the 2 columns and check if the second row is in the first via a list comprehension which should be pretty fast:

```
df['Check' ] = [b in a for a,b in zip(df['Position'],df['Subposition'])]
print(df)
```

---

```
  Position Subposition  Check
0        L           R  False
1        L           L   True
2       LR           L   True
3      SRU           L  False
```